# When is ReDim unnecessary in Excel VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I was under the impression that one needed to use the `ReDim` statement to allocate a dynamic array.

For instance, in the below `Sub` I'm declaring a dynamic array with `Dim` (i.e.   `Dim arr() as String`) and then allocating space with `ReDim` (i.e. `ReDim arr(1 to 4)`).

```
Sub test_with_ReDim()
    Dim s As String
    
    s = "Red,Yellow,Green,Blue"

    Dim arr() As String
    ReDim arr(1 To 4)

    arr = Split(s, ",")
    
    Dim i As Variant
    
    For Each i In arr
        Debug.Print i
    Next i
End Sub
```

However, it turns out that the line `ReDim arr(1 to 4)` is unnecessary and that the below code (with the `ReDim` line commented out) compiles and produces the desired output.

```
Sub test_without_ReDim()
    Dim s As String
    
    s = "Red,Yellow,Green,Blue"

    Dim arr() As String
    ' ReDim arr(1 To 4)

    arr = Split(s, ",")
    
    Dim i As Variant
    
    For Each i In arr
        Debug.Print i
    Next i
End Sub
```

My question, therefore, is when is it necessary to use `ReDim` with dynamic arrays and when is it not necessary to use `ReDim` with dynamic arrays?

I think dynamic arrays of type `variant` are one case where `ReDim` is unnecessary but wasn't aware of any others until I discovered the above example.

Is there some guiding principle to help make sense of the above example and are there any other cases where `ReDim` is not needed?

Answer (score 0):

**Dynamic**

It gets its dimensions when you create it. IE not when you `Dim` it but when you put data in by some means, such as `Array()` or `Split()`.

**Non and Dynamic Arrays**

This is what `Redim` is for is for. (normally you declare with `Dim` unless you don't know at compile time).

> Declares dynamic-array variables, and allocates or reallocates storage
> space at procedure level.
>
> `ReDim [Preserve] varname(subscripts) [, varname(subscripts)] . . .`
> **Arguments**
>
> **Preserve**  Preserves the data in an existing array when you
> change the size of the last dimension.
>
> **varname**  Name of the variable;
> follows standard variable naming conventions.
>
> **subscripts**  Dimensions
> of an array variable; up to 60 multiple dimensions may be declared.
> The subscripts argument uses the following syntax:  upper [,upper] . .
> .
>
> The lower bound of an array is always zero.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The ReDim statement is used to size or resize a dynamic array
> that has already been formally declared using a Private, Public, or
> Dim statement with empty parentheses (without dimension subscripts).
> You can use the ReDim statement repeatedly to change the number of
> elements and dimensions in an array.
>
> If you use the Preserve keyword, you can resize only the last array
> dimension, and you can't change the number of dimensions at all. For
> example, if your array has only one dimension, you can resize that
> dimension because it is the last and only dimension. However, if your
> array has two or more dimensions, you can change the size of only the
> last dimension and still preserve the contents of the array.
>
> The following example shows how you can increase the size of the last
> dimension of a dynamic array without erasing any existing data
> contained in the array.
>
> `ReDim X(10, 10, 10) . . .`

> `ReDim Preserve X(10, 10, 15)`

**Caution**

> If you make an array smaller than it was originally, data in the
> eliminated elements is lost. When variables are initialized, a numeric
> variable is initialized to 0 and a string variable is initialized to a
> zero-length string (""). A variable that refers to an object must be
> assigned an existing object using the Set statement before it can be
> used. Until it is assigned an object, the declared object variable has
> the special value Nothing.